# How to access current mapped tuple while mapping a list?

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, tuples

Could someone please help me to avoid duplicate computations in the Scala mapping below?

```
(for (i <- 0 to 20) yield i).map((i: Int) => (
  math.pow(2, i),
  math.pow(2, i).toString, // duplicate computation
  math.sqrt(i),
  math.sqrt(i).toString    // duplicate computation
))
```

Comment: Minor note: `(for (i <- 0 to 20) yield i)` is a complicated way to write `(0 to 20)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `map` here and you can introduce new values inside for-comprehension:

```
for {
   i <- 0 to 20
   pow2 = math.pow(2, i)
   sqrti = math.sqrt(i)
} yield (pow2, pow2.toString, sqrti, sqrti.toString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the shortest answer, but what seems the easiest to understand to me: define a method and use it inside the `.map` :

```
def powAndSqrt(i:Int) = {
  val pow  = math.pow(2,i)
  val sqrt = math.sqrt(i)
  (pow, pow.toString, sqrt, sqrt.toString)
}

(0 to 20).map(powAndSqrt)
```

Comment: Thank you for this one! But, I would prefer to keep the yield way.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the other answers, which are fine, you can declare vals at will within any block, so :

```
(1 to 20) map { i => 
  val pow2 = math.pow(2,i)
  val sqrti = math.sqrt(i)
  (pow2, pow2.toString, sqrti, sqrti.toString)
}
```

the `for` will be expanded to exactly that and is probably more pleasant, but it might be useful to know that you can do the same in an anonymous function block as in another block.